# Error - "expression must have a class type" - c++

Tags: c++

I have my own LinkedList class, and when I'm creating an instance in the main i get the "expression must have class type" error.
I have a default c'tor in the LinkedList class.

so when I'm trying to do this :

```
    LinkedList<Animal> aL();

    for (int i = 0; i < numOfAnimals; i++)
    {

        aL.addLast(*animals[i]);
    }

    cout << aL << endl;
```

it won't compile.
but if I declare like this:

```
    LinkedList<Animal> aL = LinkedList<Animal>();
```

it works.
of course that the secont option isn't efficient, and i rather use the first one.
can anyone explain me why it doesn't work or how to fix it?
Thnaks!

Comment: This is an instance of the "most vexing parse"

Comment: `LinkedList<Animal> aL();` -- That is a function declaration.  Look closely at it.

Comment: @VittorioRomeo As far as I know, the term "most vexing parse" refers to a bit more involved variation of this, like `A a(B());`

Comment: @lisyarus - Considering it's not an official term, but a colloquial one, I don't see why not expand it. It's all very vexing if one isn't used to it.

Comment: @StoryTeller Doesn't matter whether the term is official or not. It already *has* a defined meaning in C++ world. If one uses the term to mean something different, he may come into trouble. I agree that this could also be called "most vexing parse", since it is rather confusing sometimes, but still: the term already has a meaning.

Comment: @lisyarus - No trouble. Colloquialisms shift often, and with use.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The line

```
LinkedList<Animal> aL();
```

is not creating an instance of a `LinkedList<Animal>`, but is declaring a function `aL` with no arguments and `LinkedList<Animal>` as its return type.

To create an object using the default constructor, just don't use any braces:

```
LinkedList<Animal> aL;
```

Alternatively, if you wish to be that explicit, you can use curly braces from C++11

```
LinkedList<Animal> aL{};
```

Or, if you like function call syntax that much, you can

```
LinkedList<Animal> aL = LinkedList<Animal>();
```

or even

```
auto aL = LinkedList<Animal>();
```